# Unity3D - Clones won't get destroyed by script

Tags: unity, unityscript

I need some help making this script work.

```
#pragma strict

function OnMouseDown () {
Destroy (gameObject);
}
```

Basicly what the script does is that it destroys the objects that the player clicks on.I also got another object which has a script attached to it,which makes it spawn other objects.

The script clones the objects and makes it spawn multiple times.I attached the first script to the prefab but when I click on it,it won't be destroyed.If I click on the original prefab it works,but not on the clones created by the other script.

Anyone has any idea ?

Thank you.

Edit #1

Spawn script :

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Spawner : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject[] obj;
    public float spawnMin = 1f;
    public float spawnMax = 2f;

    void Start () {
        Spawn ();
    }

    void Spawn() 
    {
        Instantiate(obj[Random.Range(0, obj.GetLength(0))],transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
        Invoke ("Spawn", Random.Range (spawnMin, spawnMax));
    }

}
```

Comment: `I attached the first script to the prefab` Did you attach the script before or after instantiating clones? The clone objects need to have the script attached.

Comment: I actualy DON'T KNOW how instantiation works...Im new in scripting.

Comment: If you don't know how instantiation works, perhaps you should ask about that instead.

Comment: Since you don't seem responsive to my previous suggestion to ask about instantiation in your question, let me try a different tack: in your question you said the first script `makes it spawn multiple times.` If you don't know how instantiation works, what did you mean by "spawn"?

Comment: By spawn I mean clone a prefab and put it on the scene multiple times.

Comment: er, all you've done is restate what's in your question: "The script clones the objects and makes it spawn" I assumed "clone" meant instantiating, but since you don't know how instantiation works, what *does* it mean?

Comment: Can you be more clear,I don't understand a single word you're saying.Im just trying to destroy a clone made by a spawner script on click/touch.And yeah Im a newbie in unity and scripting but Im learning day after day.

Comment: You said you don't know how to instantiate. So what *are* you doing to spawn objects?

Comment: Im using a script I found on a video tutorial.After looking at it again ,it seem to be using instantiation.

Answer (score 0):

The code above is indeed correct, you **MUST** instantiate your objects though!
*I understand how one cannot have knowledge on this topic, we all start somewhere.*

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class SpawnScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float Delay = 4f;       // Time before spawning starts, to allow scene to render/catch up
    public float Difference = 7f;  // Time between each spawn
    public GameObject[] enemies;   // Array of your enemy prefabs.


    void Start ()
    {
        InvokeRepeating("SpawnEnemy", Delay, Difference);
    }


    void SpawnEnemy ()
    {
        // Instantiate one random enemy every time this is called
        int enemyIndex = Random.Range(0, enemies.Length);
        Instantiate(enemies[enemyIndex], transform.position, transform.rotation);

    }
}
```